# Django get the last part of the path in the URL in the template

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I have a path https:///something.com/asset/asset_app/location_laptop/POA/

I want to exract "POA" part and write in my template {{ request.##### }}

how would i do that?

URL patterns:

```
path("asset_app/location_laptop/export-excel/<str:location>/", views.LocationLaptopListExcelView.as_view(), name="asset_app_location_laptop_list-excel"),
```

Comment: Can you please share the URL pattern(s) to that view?

Comment: path("asset_app/location_laptop/export-excel/<str:location>/", views.LocationLaptopListExcelView.as_view(), name="asset_app_location_laptop_list-excel"),

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `POA` is the `location` URL parameter. You can access this with:

```
{{ view.kwargs.location }}
```

The `view` object is always passed to the template, and the named URL parameters are stored as `.kwargs` attribute. We can obtain `kwargs['location']` with `.location` in a Django template variable.